# why vulnerabilities keep show when i installing firebase to next.js?

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, next.js

I just want to try using firebase with nextjs. i tried installing firebase to next.js twice in a different project but i found the same problem call **"npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0"** when installing it. is there a way to fix this? if there is, I really appreciate the help.

i tried **"npm audit fix --force**" but the result still show 4 high severity vulnerabilities and i have no idea how to fix that. if that "problem" doesn't matter and i can work fine with it, then I hope someone can confirm what's going on. thank you

Comment: The error message is telling you that you should replace uglify-es with uglify-js.  If this isn't something you have control over in your project, then you will need to accept that npm will continue warn you about it.  If you think this is a problem with Firebase, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) and report the problem.

Comment: I'll try changing uglify-es first. if it's still not possible maybe I'll ask firebase what's really going on. thanks for helping